# Cross-Origin Request Blocked - MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have both the back and front end running on localhost but on different ports. I have set up the CORS headers etc and all works fine, i.e. all requests from the front end (e.g. logging in, creating user accounts etc) all works fine.

Now, I have been trying to incorporate file upload basically following http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/12/07/file-upload-with-angularjs-and-nodejs/. However, when I try to upload files, I always get the error (e.g. in Firefox)

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/uploads/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I thought I had set up the CORS headers correctly so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Perhaps I am setting the one of the headers in the interceptor incorrectly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the relevant code:

**Express Server**

```
            .all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // for the moment I allow all domains
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
                res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-type, Accept, X-Access-Token, X-Key');
                if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
                    res.status(200).end();
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            });
```

**Angular Client Settings**

```
            .config([
                '$stateProvider',
                '$urlRouterProvider', 
                '$httpProvider', 

                function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

                    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');

                    ...

                }
            ]);

            .factory('TokenInterceptor', ['$q', '$window', function($q, $window) {

                return {
                    request: function(config) {
                        config.headers = config.headers || {};
                        if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                            config.headers['X-Access-Token'] = $window.sessionStorage.token;
                            config.headers['X-Key'] = $window.sessionStorage.username;
                            config.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";
                        }
                        return config || $q.when(config);
                    },

                    response: function(response) {

                    if (response.status === 401) {
                        // handle the case when the user is not authenticated
                        alert('You are not authenticated!');

                        ...

                    }

                  return response || $q.when(response);
                }
              };
            }]);
```

**Client Upload using ng-file-upload**

*HTML*

```
        <form  name="up.upload_form">
            Single Image with validations
        <input 
            type="file" 
            ngf-select 
            ng-model="up.file" 
            name="file" 
            ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
            accept="image/*" 
            ngf-max-size="20MB" 
            />
        Image thumbnail: <img style="width:100px;" ng-show="!!up.file" ngf-thumbnail="up.file"/>
        <i ng-show="up.upload_form.file.$error.required">*required</i><br>
        <i ng-show="up.upload_form.file.$error.maxSize">File too large 
        {{up.file.size / 1000000|number:1}}MB: max 20M</i>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="up.submit()">submit</button>
        <p>{{up.progress}}</p>
    </form>
```

*Controller*

```
        var vm = this;
        vm.submit = function(){
            if (vm.upload_form.file.$valid && vm.file) {
                vm.upload(vm.file); //call upload function
            }
        }

        vm.upload = function (file) {
            Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/uploads/', 
                data:{file:file}  
            }).then(function (resp) {
                if(resp.data.error_code === 0){
                    $window.alert('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ');
                } else {
                    $window.alert('an error occured');
                }
            }, function (resp) {
                console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
                $window.alert('Error status: ' + resp.status);
            }, function (evt) { 
                console.log(evt);
                var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
                vm.progress = 'progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ';
            });
        };
```

Comment: I use to work with $httpProvider in my App config in addition to what you have done.. things like "$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;" and "delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];"

Comment: @Rodrigo: Thanks, would you mind giving a few for details about what you think I should add?

Comment: In my case i needed cross domain in the API side (server-side) and in my Angular application (if you allow in front-end and the server don't you'll have a problem). One possibility is the server negating the request or some kind of configuration. Another point is to think about the credentials (if it's necessary), you can use the config to set some standards to requests (for example 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx xxxx'). You can delete or set some header keys like 'X-Requested-With', you have set this one while i removed that.. It will depend the way the server expect and allow the request.

Comment: It seems the issue is with the config.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json" in the interceptor i.e. when removing it all works fine.